# Aplicando interface em Controllers

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Tenho alguns *controllers* que fazem chamada aos seus respectivos *models* e gostaria de aplicar interface neles. Criei uma interface com alguns métodos que seria importante todos implementarem, da seguinte maneira:

```
public interface IController<E> {

    public void adicionar(E Element);

    public void editar(E element);

    public List<E> listar();

    public void excluir(E element);
}
```

`E` é o tipo de objeto que o *controller* trata.(Ex. `UsuarioController` vai implementar `IController<Usuario>`).

Atualmente no sistema, todos os *controllers* já possuem estes métodos da interface. O problema é que em um dos *controllers*, o método `adicionar(E element)` precisa retornar o mesmo objeto que foi adicionado, e não `void`, pois este objeto retorna com o id registrado no banco, logo em seguida, exibo os dados deste objeto em tela.

Diante do exposto acima, como posso aplicar uma interface a classes com comportamentos comuns(como os *controllers*) e uma delas possuir um dos métodos do "contrato" diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está dizendo é que ora você quer isto:

```
public interface IController<E> {
   void adicionar(E Element);
    ...
}
```

E ora isto:

```
public interface IController<E> {
   E adicionar(E Element);
    ...
}
```

Não é possível variar o tipo de retorno dessa forma.

É uma tentação comum querer ser muito granular ao definir uma API. Você gostaria que cada detalhe refletisse exatamente o comportamento de cada objeto.

Porém, quanto mais variação, mais complexidade e na grande maioria dos casos vale a pena sacrificar a economia de uma ou duas linhas de código para obter consistência.

## Mantenha a consistência

A solução comum para este caso específico é sempre retornar o objeto incluído. É uma boa prática porque o objeto, após ter os dados incluídos no banco geralmente ganha um ID gerado, timestamp ou algum outro atributo gerado no tempo da inserção e que pode ser necessário no sistema.

Mesmo que hoje você só veja a necessidade para um caso, isso tende a crescer na medida em que o sistema evolui.

Nos casos em que não há nada a fazer, você pode simplesmente retornar o mesmo objeto que recebeu no parâmetro:

```
@Override
public Entidade adicionar(Entidade entidade) {
    //insere no banco
    return entidade;
}
```

Vantagens:

- Não custa nada
- API consistente (exceções e variações de comportamento aumentam a complexidade do sistema)
- Facilita manutenção do sistema

Desvantagens:

- Uma linha de código a mais?
- Não consegui pensar em nada concreto...

## API granular

Se, mesmo com o que escrevi acima você ainda desejar ser granular, a solução é definir interfaces de forma mais granular.

Exemplo:

```
interface IGeneralController<E> {
    //...
}
interface IReturningAppenderController<E> {
    E adicionar(E Element);
}
interface IAppenderController<E> {
    void adicionar(E Element);
}

public class Controller implements IGeneralController<Entidade>, IReturningAppenderController<Entidade> {
    @Override
    public Entidade adicionar(Entidade entidade) {
        //insere no banco
        return entidade;
    }
}
public class OtherController implements IGeneralController<Entidade>, IAppenderController<Entidade> {
    @Override
    public void adicionar(Entidade entidade) {
        //insere no banco
    }
}
```

Parece até legal, mas agora você tem um código mais verboso e um monte de condições e *casts* que você terá que fazer em tempo de execução.

Comment: Então, retornando o mesmo item, mesmo que por hora eu ainda não tenha uso para ele no sistema, não seria "dirty code"?

Comment: @DiegoF Se você olhar a definição de "dirty code" na [Wikipédia](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dirty_code) e em outros sites vai ver que é justamente o contrário. Falta de um padrão, consistência e dificuldade de manutenção são sinônimos de "dirty code". A não ser que você veja alguma razão porque um return vai deixar gerar problemas pro seu código mesmo que nem sempre usado, não tem motivo para achar isso. Você pode achar desnecessário e optar por outra alternativa sem problemas, mas se pensar em questão de manutenção do sistema, usar uma interface diferente tem muito mais chances de mudar

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi bem seria isto:

```
public E adicionar(E Element);
```

Fora isso, não pode usar a mesma interface. O que poderia é herdar dessa existente:

```
public interface IControllerEspecial<E> extends IController<E> {
    public E adicionar(E Element);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/Controller.java).

Isto não resolve totalmente o problema. O ideal seria uma gambiarra maior (que por vezes é necessário). Teria que criar uma interface sem este método `adicionar`, aí criar essa `IController` estendendo com esse método com assinatura retornando `void`. Já a `IControllerXXX` teria o mesmo método com assinatura retornando `E`. Do jeito que eu mostrei teria dois métodos `adicionar` com assinaturas diferentes.

Outra forma é ter interfaces completamente separadas, mas aí começa jogar por terra o mecanismo, porque você começa ter que se lembrar que tem que usar a interface auxiliar. O que acontece se usar a `IController` e esquecer de usar a auxiliar só com o método que causa problemas? Percebe que esta solução é estragar o *design* correto para solucionar um problema específico? De repente você tem uma interface de CRUD sem o C. Me parece que conceitualmente isto esteja errado, o contrato fica capenga.

Particularmente eu tentaria mudar algum coisa pra normalizar as operações, fazer retornar sempre a mesma coisa é uma delas, não sei se é o ideal pro seu caso.

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas ai todos os controllers terão que retornar um objeto, por causa de um método em apenas um deles..

Comment: Mas essa é a ideia da Interface não? Criar um molde para algo que tera comportamento/estrutura semelhante.

Comment: Igual, semelhante não, quando é só semelhante, precisa de outra interface.

Comment: Esse IControllerEspecial parece ser próximo do que estou precisando,  vou testar aqui. (off-topic: é estranho ver uma interface sendo estendida, mesmo que ambas sejam interfaces hehe)

Comment: Bigown, o problema é que só tenho 2 escolhas: ou obrigo todos os controllers a ficar retornando NULL só pra um deles retornar algo(o que queria evitar), ou adapto/isolo o controller "problemático"(que é a opção que estou tentando descobrir com vocês).

Comment: Não deu certo, a IDE reclama que os 2 métodos adicionar das interfaces estão em conflito. Parece que essa minha forma de pensar não e a certa para o problema, vou ver o que posso alterar.

Comment: Leia a resposta, eu editei. Mas não tem boa solução pra isso a não ser mudar o que está fazendo.

Comment: Não faço a minima de como resolver isso por outra forma. Não posso tornar void nesse método, pois preciso exibir os dados com o id que o banco o salvou. Você acha que seria "Dirty Code" eu fazer todos retornarem null só para se adaptarem a ele? Não há outra forma de retornar o id do banco, dos demais campos do objeto que retorno na tabela, somente o id é indexavel e unico.

Comment: Eu acho. Mas não posso falar sem conhecer o problema todo. Claro que tem situações que o ideal não é possível. Eu acho que o conceito todo da aplicação **pode** estar errado :) Quando você começa fazer a casa torta, ela não endireita mais.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown! Você está querendo atribuir dois comportamentos a uma mesma interface. Isso faz com que o conceito de contrato perca o sentido. O que você pode fazer é ter 3 interfaces. Uma comum a todas, e duas com o adicionar() específico. Assim, você implementaria duas delas. Você também pode segmentar interfaces por operação, editar, listar, adicionar. Mesmo assim, como o @bigown disse, resolver a questão da sintaxe não te livrará de problemas futuros se a arquitetura te trouxer alguns problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da sua implementação você poderá utilizar uma abordagem diferente. Ter um método com um void e outro com o return do objeto. Poderia ter na sua interface:

```
public interface IController<E> {

 public void adicionar(E Element);

 public void editar(E element);

 public List<E> listar();

 public void excluir(E element);

 public Element retornaElement();
//Se você controla os id's pode utiliza-lo como parâmetro. Caso não, caso sejam incrementais irá sempre buscar o último registro inserido.
}
```

É preciso ficar atento quanto a concorrência, dependendo do seu tipo de aplicação para esta operação. Outro ponto de atenção é quanto a garantir que o commit do comando de inserção no banco realmente existiu para que você consiga de fato recuperar o último registro inserido.

Desta forma, sua implementação poderia ficar:

```
public Element implementacaoController(){
  // código 
  adicionar(element);
  // garantia de commit e conclusão da transação
  return retornaElement(); //aqui dependendo da sua implementação poderia passar o id do element, ou seja, element.getID(), ou simplesmente recuperar o último registro inserido.
}
```

Caso tenha dificuldades com o comportamento do método em inserir e recuperar durante a mesma execução. Experimente trabalhar com métodos isolados sendo exibidos através de um terceiro método.

Dependendo do seu contexto, talvez essas abordagem atenda a sua necessidade.
Abraço!

Comment: Ai todas as classes vão ter que implementar esse método, gerando código desnecessário, o que eu quero evitar. Optei por adaptar todos os métodos adicionar() com o mesmo retorno, assim, como relatado pelo colega luiz, o máximo que perco é funcionalidade que, por ora, não vou usar.

Comment: Entendi. @DiegoF, rola um interface e uma implementação genérica no seu código com esse trecho de código? Similar as utilizadas para os DAO's. Nela você poderia deixar implementado esse comportamento e quando tivesse que implementar em um novo controller não teria a necessidade de redundância do trecho do código. Ao implementar já teria a inserção e o retorno do elemento em uma nova chamada de um método já tratado para esse comportamento. Mas claro, talvez não seja interessante ter algo genérico unicamente para essa necessidade. Fica ai uma sugestão caso seja algo realmente necessário.