# Passar a execução de um determinado método para o SwingWorker como argumento

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Tenho uma pequena aplicação em `swing`, onde gostaria de exibir um progresso quando determinadas ações fossem executadas

Como exemplo, tenho o `listener` abaixo que é executado quando um `JComboBox` é alterado. Ele pega o item selecionado(que neste caso é um objeto `Setor` com *id* e *nome*), e passa o *id* pro `CadastranteComboModel`, que por sua vez, busca no banco a lista de cadastrantes daquele setor passado e exibe em um outro `JComboBox` de cadastrantes:

```
private void comboSetorItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        final int setorId = ((Setor) evt.getItem()).getId();
        CadastranteComboModel cadComboModel = new CadastranteComboModel(setorId);
        comboUsuario.setModel(cadComboModel);
```

O problema é que essa comunicação com o banco(que é em HSQL) demora um pouco, pois a aplicação é executada de um local de rede em modo Stand-alone. Então criei um `JDialog` apenas para exibir uma `JProgressBar` infinita, mas não sei como passar a execução da linha `CadastranteComboModel cadComboModel = new CadastranteComboModel(setorId);`, por exemplo, para o `SwingWorker` no `doInBackground()`.

Tentando contornar este problema, bolei esse código dentro do `listener` citado:

```
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            // esta é a janela que fiz a parte
            //com a JProgressBar infinita
            ProgressDialog progress;

             //esse método que ativa o progresso pelo publish()
            // e executa a linha a seguir em uma Thread separada
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                publish();
                CadastranteComboModel cadComboModel = new CadastranteComboModel(setorId);
                comboUsuario.setModel(cadComboModel);
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {
                // getInstance() é o frame da tela como referencia
                //esse método é "decorativo"
                changeStatusComponent(getInstance(), false);
                //chama e exibe a JDialog com a JProgressBar
                progress = new ProgressDialog(getInstance(), true);
                progress.setLocationRelativeTo(getInstance());
                progress.setVisible(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                //quando termina a execução no doInBackground
                // fecho a tela de progresso
                progress.dispose();
                changeStatusComponent(getInstance(), true); 
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
```

Funciona perfeitamente para o caso, só que eu vou ter que repetir o mesmo bloco de código em outros 7 ou 8 métodos (alguns até retornam valores), que possuem alguma ação que depende de consulta no banco, como este aqui que exclui um oficio da tabela e do banco:

```
private void btnExcluirOficioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    int indiceRowModel = this.tabela.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(this.tabela.getSelectedRow());
    int intOf = (int) this.tabela.getModel().getValueAt(indiceRowModel, 0);
    Date date = (Date) this.tabela.getModel().getValueAt(indiceRowModel, 3);
    String strAno = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date);
    String strSetor = (String) this.tabela.getModel().getValueAt(indiceRowModel, 5);
    String strOficio = strSetor + " " + intOf + "-" + strAno;

    int confirma = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getInstance(), "Excluir o oficio " + strOficio + "?",
            ListaDeOficiosUI.TITULO, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (confirma == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        try {
            //por causa desta chamada, vou ter que inserir aquele bloco
            // do swingworker
            this.tableModel.removeRow(indiceRowModel);
            PrintMessageUI.exibirMsg(this.getInstance(), "Oficio" + strOficio + " excluído.");
        } catch (ExcecaoPadrao ex) {
            PrintMessageUI.exibirError(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

O que eu preciso fazer é uma classe  que herde do `swingworker` e possa receber esses métodos "problemáticos" como argumento, passando a execução deles para o `doInBackground`, mas não sei como posso fazer isso.

Existe alguma forma de passar um método como argumento para outro, e sua execução não ser realizada na chamada, e sim dentro do método que o recebeu como argumento?

> Obs.: a aplicação(o jar, no caso) é em java7, não posso fazer em java8
>   por restrições da TI(mas sugestões em java8 são bem vindas).

Comment: Esses métodos que quer executar no `doInBackground()` têm todos a mesma assinatura?

Comment: @ramaral infelizmente não :/, só se eu barrar direto nos controllers, porque como pode ser visto [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119616/28595) que fiz há alguns dias, eles tem em comum a interface com exatamente os mesmos metodos, no final, praticamente todos os métodos chamam algum controller e estes sim são padronizados por interface. Problema é que não sei se é boa prática "chamar GUI" em classe que não tem a ver com GUI, mas se essa for a unica solução...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os métodos que quer executar no `doInBackground()` tivessem todos a mesma assinatura a solução passaria por declarar uma interface e passá-la no construtor de uma classe herdada de *SwingWorker*.

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    interface Operation{
        void execute(int valor); //Altere a assinatura de acordo com a sua necessidade
    }

    Operation operation;
    int valor;
    public Worker(Operation operation, int valor){

        this.operation = operation;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        operation.execute(valor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {

        -----
        -----
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {

        -----
        -----
    }
}
```

Qualquer classe que implemente a *interface* **Operation** pode ser passada no construtor e o seu método executado no `doInBackground()`:

```
Worker worker = new Worker(myOperationClass, 10);
worker.execute();
```

---

Como isso não acontece, uma solução possível será, já que o que varia é só o código do `doInBackground()`, criar uma classe abstracta que herde de  *SwingWorker* e implementar os métodos `process()` e `done()`, deixando o método `doInBackground()` por implementar.

```
public abstract class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    //Implemente os métodos process e done

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {

        -----
        -----
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {

        -----
        -----
    }
}
```

Quando necessitar de executar um dos *tasks* crie uma instância dessa classe e então implemente o método `doInBackground()`.

```
Worker worker = new Worker(){

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        //implemente de acordo com a situação.
    }
};
worker.execute();
```

Comment: Obrigado pelos exemplos, o primeiro eu não consegui implementar porque não entendi kkk mas o segundo parece que é a solução que eu precisava! Vou testar amanhã na empresa(o código está no pc de lá) e dou um feedback.

Comment: Funcionou mesmo, obrigado :)