# Pegar Frame já iniciado a partir da "Event Dispatch Thread"

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

Tenho uma aplicação desktop em `swing`, e nela, tenho um único `JFrame` que sempre fica visível enquanto a aplicação estiver aberta. Há também alguns `JDialogs` modais dependentes deste *Frame*, que abrem a partir de determinados botões no `JFrame`.

Estou testando uma barra de progresso usando `SwingWorker`(outra pergunta feita e respondida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120325/28595)), e preciso passar o *Frame* para esta classe para poder ativar a `progressBar`, porém preciso obter a instância do Frame já aberto em outra classe diferente.

No `Frame`, possuo um método público chamado `getInstance()`, que devolve a própria instancia da janela, mas para usá-lo, preciso já ter um objeto do Frame criado, mas no caso, eu não posso criar outra instância, preciso pegar a que já está ativa.

A partir daí, pensei se talvez a EDT permitisse, de alguma forma, recuperar o Frame atual aberto, ainda mais pelo fato de que as classes onde preciso fazer essa chamada, também foram iniciadas na EDT, mas não sei como faz isso.

É possível, a partir da [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread) (EDT), recuperar este *Frame* já inicializado e visível na aplicação? Se sim, como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11574261/5524514) que encontrei no SOEn, a solução foi usar o método estático [**`getFrames()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames()), que retorna um array de Frames criados pela aplicação. Como este método também pode retornar Frames auxiliares criados pela JVM, dentro do laço eu verifico se o *Frame* é uma instância do meu *Frame* principal, e somente assim tenho certeza de que o *Frame* capturado é exatamente a minha tela.

```
Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
        for (Frame f : frames) {
            //ListaDeOficiosUI é o nome da minha tela que
            // estende JFrame
            if (f instanceof ListaDeOficiosUI) {
                this.instance = f;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Talvez não seja uma solução tão adequada de se usar, mas paliativamente, resolveu meu problema.