# Problemas com Array

Tags: java

Eu tô fazendo um sistema de reconhecimento facial, e só falta isso pra eu finalizar tudo. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < facesDetectadas.size(); i++) {
                                Rect dadosFace = facesDetectadas.get(i);
                                rectangle(imagemCamera, dadosFace, new Scalar(255, 255, 0, 0), 2, i, i);
                                Mat faceCapturada = new Mat(imagemCinza, dadosFace);
                                opencv_imgproc.resize(faceCapturada, faceCapturada, new Size(160, 160));

                                IntPointer rotulo = new IntPointer(1);
                                DoublePointer confianca = new DoublePointer(1);
                                reconhecedor.predict(faceCapturada, rotulo, confianca);
                                int predicao = rotulo.get(0);
                                String nome;
                                if (predicao == -1) {
                                    nome = "Desconhecido";
                                } else {
                                    nome = pessoas[predicao] + " - " + confianca.get(0);
                                    campoid.setText(String.valueOf(predicao));
                                    rec();
                                }
                                int x = Math.max(dadosFace.tl().x() - 10, 0);
                                int y = Math.max(dadosFace.tl().y() - 10, 0);
                                putText(imagemCamera, nome, new Point(x, y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.7, new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 2));
                            }
```

E mais em cima, eu tenho no metódo "rec" eu tenho o array mesmo:

Segue o metódo rec:

```
private void rec() {
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            conecta.conexao();
            try {
                String SQL = "SELECT * FROM reconhecer where id=" + campoid.getText() + "";
                conecta.executaSQL(SQL);

                while (conecta.rs.next()) {
                    camponome.setText(conecta.rs.getString(1));
                    campoidade.setText(conecta.rs.getString(2));
                    campoemail.setText(conecta.rs.getString(3));
                    campobloco.setText(conecta.rs.getString(5));
                    campoapto.setText(conecta.rs.getString(6));
                    campocondominio.setText(conecta.rs.getString(7));
                    System.out.println("Pessoa idêntificada como: " + conecta.rs.getString(1));
                    System.out.println("---------------");

                    Array identificacao = conecta.rs.getArray(2);
                    String[] pessoas = (String[]) identificacao.getArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println(pessoas[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            conecta.desconecta();
            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Motivo de eu ter feito separado: Eu fiz um swing worker, e isso facilita a não ficar travando a aplicação.

Meu problema e minha dúvida: O meu `pessoas` onde tá o `if`, não reconhece o `pessoas` que tá no `rec`, como posso fazer pra deixar o `pessoas` visível pra tudo? Eu tentei usar global mas não funciona também.

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** ou um código mais relevante, porque esse codigo ai nao diz muito pra te ajudar em relacao a duvida.

Comment: Olá, Abner! Poderia compartilhar os dois métodos inteiros? Você não pode passar `pessoas` via parâmetro para o `rec`?

Comment: O método que contém esse `if` precisa receber como parâmetro o `array` com o qual você quer trabalhar dentro do `if`.

Comment: doInBackground executa sobre uma thread diferente, voce nao irá conseguir compartilhar variaveis, nem publicas, entre o que estiver fora e dentro dele.

Comment: Sim, mas se eu colocar o array ali, ele precisa "chamar" os outros parametros, como por exemplo, o `conecta.rs....`, Eu tentei colocar ali, mas trava toda a aplicação, em toda verificação no banco, ele trava tudo.

Comment: Fica mais facil te ajudar se fornecer um **[mcve]**, pois assim fica melhor pra analisar o codigo. Esses trechos soltos dificultam qualquer analise mais precisa.

Comment: Ou pode ler e analisar [**essa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120435/28595) e ver se serve pro seu caso.

Comment: @Articuno está certo sobre a questão da Thread, mas aí você não vai removê-la. Você pode mudar essa variável par a ser um singleton thread safe. Olha essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944184/instance-variable-in-a-singleton-class-accessed-by-multiple-threads.

Comment: Sem resultado... Eu só não coloco o `pessoas` no meu `if ` por que o sistema trava todo. Vou ver se consigo algo por aqui. Obrigado.